# Facebook object data (like) remains empty, except under own fb account

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a webpage build in APS.NET C# which checks if a user is logged in at Facebook.
Then it checks if the corresponding Facebook page is liked. There is a like button on the page. If they click on the like button they go to a specific page.

This all works fine but when a user who already liked the facebook page goes to my webpage, nothing happens. I constructed some code from the many topics here on stackoverflow. It works, BUT only if i use my own facebook account. If a random user does this the object data remains emtpy.

Am i missing something in my code or a misconfiguration of my facebookapp?

**Update**: Added scope parameter

Javascript:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

      //
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{app id}',                
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true, 
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.0'
      });



      //
      FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.status == 'connected') {
              var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
              var page_id = "{page id}";
              var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=" + page_id + " and uid=" + user_id;

              /* make the API call */
              FB.api(
                  "/me/likes/{page id}",
                  function (response) {
                    console.log(response);

                    if (response && !response.error) {

                      if(response.data.length == 0) {                              

                        location.href = 'stay...';
                      }
                      else {
                        location.href = 'go to specific page';
                      }

                    }



                  }
              );


          } else {
            // user is not logged in
          }
      }, {scope: 'user_likes'});

// redirect after like
          FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
              function(response) {
                  location.href = '...';                
              }
          );

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

ASP/HTML:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/{page}" data-width="300" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: You need user_likes permission to see what a user liked

Comment: Alright, i added the user_likes in the scope(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.0#permissions). No real results. Is it placed right? Any help is really appreciated :)